# Different functions with the same name and how to call them in LLVM IR

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-ir

I am writing a toy compiler for a pascal-like language.
Suppose I have a pseudocode like the following:

```
define main

   define foo
      define b
         writeInteger: 1
      call b

   define bar
      define b
        writeInteger: 2
      call b

   call foo
   call bar
```

where two different `b` functions are defined inside of `foo` and `bar`.

So the corresponding LLVM IR function for `b` inside of `foo` is

```
define void @b(%foo_type* %foo_frame) {
...
```

And for `b` inside of `bar` is

```
define void @b.1(%bar_type* %bar_frame) {
...
```

The problem is that when I try to call the function `b`, LLVM automatically assumes that I am calling the `void @b`, but I have no way to call `void @b.1`.

So, the printed result is `11` but I would like it to be `12`.

I use the `TheModule->getFunction("b");` command to access the LLVM function Object.

So, how can I call the `b` function defined inside of `bar`?

UPDATE:

As AlexDenisov pointed out I could name the first b as `main_foo_b` and the second as `main_bar_b`.
So I could then call the right function `b`, by finding out from which part of the code I am calling b. I will try that by holding a list of all of the function names until now(that have not been closed). Lets call it `function_names_list`.

So then when I call the `b` function that is inside `main` and `foo` I would call `main_foo_b` because `function_names_list=["main","foo"]`. And when I call the `b` function that is inside `main` and `bar` I would call `main_bar_b` because `function_names_list=["main","bar"]`.
That will probably solve the problem for the current example.

But in an example like the following:

```
define main

   define f

      writeInteger: 1

   define g

      define f

         writeInteger: 2

      call f

   define h
      call f 


   call g     # prints 2
   call f     # prints 1
   call h     # prints 1
```

I would also need to check in which nesting level the function is. By nesting level I mean inside of how many enclosing functions I currently am. `main` has zero nesting levels, `main_f`,`main_g` and `main_h` have 1 nesting level and `main_g_f` has two nesting levels.

I would need to check the nesting level because, I would need to change how I call `f` inside of `h`.I would have to call it as `main_f` and not `main_h_f`.By knowing that the `f` I am trying to call is at the previous nesting level, I can then use all but one elements from `function_names_list` (`function_names_list[0:n-1]`) in order to get the name `main_f`.

Comment: If you defined it as `@b.1` in LLVM, you'll also have to access it using the name `b.1`, not `b`.

Comment: `TheModule->getFunction("b.1");`?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. The problem with using it as ```TheModule->getFunction("b.1");``` is that I do not know which ```b``` to call when. The function calls ```TheModule->getFunction(name);``` The name will be a string ```"b"``` because that is what the parser will read. Is there another way I can get the correct "b" function, meaning "b.1"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the SO, Nik.

Internally, all the global values (such as functions, variables, and aliases) live in hash-table-like storage inside of an LLVM module where the name serves as a key. In order to avoid collisions, LLVM adds suffixes to the function names.

I guess in this case you have to add some sort of namespacing, i.e. name the first `b` as `main_foo_b` and the second as `main_bar_b`. This way you can clearly differentiate between the 'colliding' names.

I hope this helps :)

**UPD:**

Now it seems I went a bit too far and the suggestion by @arnt sounds more reasonable. Your solution with `function_names_list` is the right direction. Usually, this is solved by a so-called [Symbol Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_table): a symbol table is just a key-value data structure that also has a pointer to the parent symbol table. The keys in your case are the function names, and the values are emitted LLVM functions.

You start with a global symbol table (for the whole translation unit), then whenever you enter a new scope you create a new symbol table and set the parent to the "previous" symbol table. Then, when you need to emit a call to the function you look for the named function in the current symbol table, if there is none, then you walk up and look at the parent symbol table. Do it recursively until you reach the global symbol table, in which case a missing function can be reported as an error.

Here is an example for your first code snippet:

```
global_table:
  scope = <whole translation unit>
  parent = null
  "main" = <main function>

main_table:
  scope = <main function>
  parent = global_table
  "foo" = <foo function>
  "bar" = <bar function>

foo_table:
  scope = <foo function>
  parent = main_table
  "b" = <b function>

bar_table:
  scope = <bar function>
  parent = main_table
  "b" = <b.1 function>
```

(Tables for `b` and `b.1` are empty, so I skipped them for brevity).

Then, depending on the scope (`foo` or `bar`) you'll start looking in either `foo_table` or `bar_table` and should find the right `b` function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I think that your solution might work for this current example.
I need to keep the names of the functions and then call b like you said.
But in an example where I would also have inside main an ```h``` function which would call the ```f``` function, I would also have to check in which nesting level the function is because inside ```h``` I would need to call ```main_f``` and not ```main_h_f```

Comment: Sorry, I cannot see the code without formatting :) I suggest you add this snippet to the end of your question (just edit the question).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers and your guidance. I will try out the solution, and see if that helps me solve the problem

Comment: Normally you'll have a class that represents your language's functions, and one of the member fields of that class will point to the generated LLVM function. You use that member to find the LLVM function when you create your CallInst and InvokeInst objects; the name isn't all that important.

Comment: @NikMakar I updated the answer based on your `function_names_list` solution and also based on @arnt comment.

Comment: @AlexDenisov and @arnt thank you for your answers. Yes I have implemented the compiler with a symbol table. I could then search for the right function.The problem was that inside the symbol table I saved the ```function name``` as a string e.g. ```f```,along with some other values such us ```nesting level```,```entry type```, ```hash value``` etc.I could not save the ```LLVM Function Pointer``` due to some limitations (The symbol table implementation was writen in c, and the llvm part of the compiler in c++).
But I tried the solution that I wrote in the update in the question and it worked.